# Circuit: Balanced Gray code => Binary?

Tags: circuit-design, binary

I've designed a circuit that accepts a standard gray code as an input and converts to binary. However, I am needing to perform the same conversion (to binary), but with a [*balanced*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Balanced_Gray_code) gray code as the input.

For example, `0010` in my circuit is being represented a `7`, but I am instead needing to represent `9`

Attached is the conversion table that I am intending to model from which represents the *balanced* gray code.

Any thoughts on how I can redesign this circuit to accept the balanced representation and perform the conversion to binary?

[image]

[image]

---

edit, adding k-maps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95608/discussion-on-question-by-scniro-circuit-balanced-gray-code-binary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview

Gray codes, very broadly speaking, are generated by any of the many possible Hamiltonian walks (aka Hamiltonian cycle) on a hypercube (an \$N\$-cube.) All Hamiltonian cycles on the \$N\$-cube are also representative of a gray code. A Hamiltonian walk or cycle traverses all of the vertices of a hypercube without revisiting a vertex. (It is not necessary to wind up at a vertex that is directly connected to the starting vertex -- for example, on a 4D hypercube one can end on a diametrically opposite vertex.) The count of all possible Hamiltonian cycles for any given \$N\$ has been brute-force solved only for small values of \$N\$. The last paper I saw demonstrated a count for \$N=6\$ and claimed that no one had worked it out for \$N=7\$ at the time. However, others [(1) and (2)] have worked out ways to compute a boundary limit of their exponential growth. So while the actual count may not be known, a limiting figure can be worked out.

Balanced (and totally balanced) Gray codes are an interesting sub-area. For a gray code to be balanced, the bit changes must be "balanced." The most common gray code for \$N=3\$ isn't balanced, as this table shows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 & \text{Gray Code} & \text{Changes}\\\\
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  i\\\\
  0\\
  1\\
  2\\
  3\\
  4\\
  5\\
  6\\
  7\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  X_2 & X_1 & X_0\\\\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&1\\
  0&1&0\\
  1&1&0\\
  1&1&1\\
  1&0&1\\
  1&0&0\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  N_C & N_B & N_A\\\\
  0&0&1\\
  0&1&1\\
  0&1&2\\
  1&1&2\\
  1&1&3\\
  1&2&3\\
  1&2&4\\
  2&2&4\\
  \end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

In the above table, the values for \$N_C\$, \$N_B\$, and \$N_A\$ show the count of bit changes for the indicated columns, \$X_2\$, \$X_1\$, or \$X_0\$, between the indicated row \$i\$ and the row \$i+1\$. (In the last row, this is taken as being between row \$i\$ and row \$0\$.) The code isn't balanced if the difference between any of the values for \$N_C\$, \$N_B\$, or \$N_A\$ differ by more than 2 for any row. The row at \$i=6\$ clearly fails this test.

---

### Balanced Gray Code for \$N=4\$

There are a number of ways of developing a balanced gray code. Robinson and Cohn's 1981 paper (3) provides a construction method (which extends Gilbert's *ultracomposite* (4) method.) Your example is one example that might be constructed. There are others.

It's trivial to develop the k-maps from your table. Just re-sort your values as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
 \text{Gray Code} & \text{Binary Code}\\\\
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  X_3 & X_2 & X_1 & X_0\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
  {\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Y_3 & Y_2 & Y_1 & Y_0\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  \end{array}
\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

The above table makes it very easy to generate the k-maps. You can just read off the binary values in each column directly into the associated k-maps below:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Y_3&\overline{X_1}\:\overline{X_0}&\overline{X_1}\: X_0&X_1 \:X_0&X_1 \:\overline{X_0}\\
\hline
\overline{X_3}\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&1&0\\
\overline{X_3}\:X_2&1&1&1&1\\
X_3\: X_2&0&0&0&0\\
X_3\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Y_2&\overline{X_1}\:\overline{X_0}&\overline{X_1}\: X_0&X_1 \:X_0&X_1 \:\overline{X_0}\\
\hline
\overline{X_3}\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&1&1\\
\overline{X_3}\:X_2&0&0&0&0\\
X_3\: X_2&0&0&1&1\\
X_3\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&1&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}\\\\
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Y_1&\overline{X_1}\:\overline{X_0}&\overline{X_1}\: X_0&X_1 \:X_0&X_1 \:\overline{X_0}\\
\hline
\overline{X_3}\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&0&1\\
\overline{X_3}\:X_2&0&1&1&0\\
X_3\: X_2&1&1&0&0\\
X_3\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&0&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
Y_0&\overline{X_1}\:\overline{X_0}&\overline{X_1}\: X_0&X_1 \:X_0&X_1 \:\overline{X_0}\\
\hline
\overline{X_3}\:\overline{X_2}&0&1&0&1\\
\overline{X_3}\:X_2&1&0&1&0\\
X_3\: X_2&0&1&0&1\\
X_3\:\overline{X_2}&1&0&1&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

It now follows that:

$$\begin{align*}
Y_3&= \overline{X_3}\, X_2 + \overline{X_2}\, X_0\\
Y_2&= X_3\, X_1 + \overline{X_2}\, X_1  + \overline{X_2}\, X_0\\
Y_1&=\overline{X_1}\, X_0 + X_3\, X_2\, \overline{X_1}  + \overline{X_3}\, X_2\, X_0 + \overline{X_2}\, X_1\, \overline{X_0}\\
Y_0&= \overline{X_3}\, X_2\, X_1\, X_0 + X_3\, \overline{X_2}\, X_1\, X_0 + X_3\, X_2\, \overline{X_1}\, X_0 + \overline{X_3}\, \overline{X_2}\, \overline{X_1}\, X_0 +\\&\quad\quad X_3\, X_2\, X_1\, \overline{X_0} + \overline{X_3}\, \overline{X_2}\, X_1\, \overline{X_0} + \overline{X_3}\, X_2\, \overline{X_1}\, \overline{X_0} + X_3\, \overline{X_2}\, \overline{X_1}\, \overline{X_0}
\end{align*}$$

I think you already know how to develop \$Y_0\$ using three 2-in XOR's. The others are more prosaic expressions and are more easily worked out.

---

### Diagram of your Hamiltonian cycle

I thought it might be interesting for you to examine the hypercube cycle for your balanced gray code. I usually find it helpful, anyway:

[image]

Just FYI.

---

### Notes

1. Contassot-Vivier, S.; Couchot, J.F. Canonical Form of Gray Codes in N-cubes. In Cellular Automata and Discrete Complex Systems, Proceedings of the 23th International Workshop on Cellular Automata and Discrete Complex Systems (AUTOMATA), Milan, Italy, 7–9 June 2017; Part 2: Regular Papers; Dennunzio, A., Formenti, E., Manzoni, L., Porreca, A.E., Eds.; Springer International Publishing: Milan, Italy, 2017; Volume LNCS-10248, pp. 68–80.
2. Wild, M. Generating all cycles, chordless cycles, and Hamiltonian cycles with the principle of exclusion. J. Discrete Algorithms 2008, 6, 93–102.
3. Robinson, J.; Cohn, M. Counting Sequences, IEEE Trans. Comput. C-30 (1981)
   17-23.
4. Gilbert, E.N. Gray Codes and Paths on the n-Cube, Bell System Technical Journal,
   Vol. 37 (1958) 815-826.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the tremendous effort. Your answer is extremely helpful and things make more sense now. I've been re-working my circuit a bit and was curious if I was far off with my original design attempt. I haven't quite solved it yet but I hope to soon.

Comment: I solved it - thank you a ton, again! You rock dude

Comment: @scniro Thanks so much for the kind words. I'm glad it helped. Do you think you could handle a similar problem now?